# Performance loss with big size of collections

Tags: mongodb

I've a collection that name "test" and has 132K documents in it. When I get first document of the collection it takes between 2-5ms but it's not same for last documation. It takes 100-200ms to pull.
So I've decided to ask the community.

**My questions**

1. What is the best document amount in one collection for the performance?
2. Why does it take so long to get last document from the collection? (I actually don't know how mongo works partially.)
3. What should I do for this issue and future problems?

Comment: are you using node.js=

Comment: I use Java for current project but may use node.js in future.

Comment: i dont know how its in java but in node.js you can add `.explain()` to the end of the query to see some query details

Comment: I basically use fineOne command to find document in the collection that has 132K documents. For the first documents there isn't any performance problem but for the last, it's not look great for me... So is there any specific rules or scheme type for that? Is it good to use just one collection for 132K documents?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some search of how mongodb works, I found the solution. I didn't use any indexes for my collection so whenever I try to pull something it scans each data and each document. After creating some indexes for my needs, it is much more faster, actually 1ms, than before.

**Conclusion**

Create indexes for your collection and your needs. It'd be effective write and read operation both. Do not forget to search more 'cause there're some options like background which prevents blocking operations while creating index.